# Time Series within R (ColumnSorting)

Tags: r, date, columnsorting

I have a csv of real-time data inputs with timestamps and I am looking to group these data in a time series of 30 mins for analysis.

A sample of the real-time data is

```
Date:  
2019-06-01 08:03:04  
2019-06-01 08:20:04  
2019-06-01 08:33:04  
2019-06-01 08:54:04  
...
```

I am looking to group them in a table with a step increment of 30 mins (i.e. 08:30, 09:00, etc..) to seek out the number of occurences during each period. I created a new csv file to access through R. This is so that I will not corrupt the formatting of the orginal dataset.

```
Date:  
2019-06-01 08:00  
2019-06-01 08:30  
2019-06-01 09:00  
2019-06-01 09:30
```

I have firstly constructed a list of 30 mins intervals by:

```
sheet_csv$Date <- as.POSIXct(paste(sheet_csv$Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "GMT") #to change to POSIXct
sheet_csv$Date <- timeDate::timeSequence(from = "2019-06-01 08:00", to = "2019-12-03 09:30", by = 1800,
                           format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", zone = "GMT")
```

I encountered an error `"Error in x[[idx]][[1]] : this S4 class is not subsettable"` for this interval.

I am relatively new to R. Please do help out where you can. Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the `timeDate` package for something like this. One package that is very helpful to manipulate dates and times is `lubridate` - you may want to consider going forward.

I used your example and added another date/time for illustration.

To create your 30 minute intervals, you could use `cut` and `seq.POSIXt` to create a sequence of date/times with 30 minute breaks. I used your minimum date/time to start with (rounding down to nearest hour) but you can also specify another date/time here.

Use of `table` will give you frequencies after `cut`.

```
sheet_csv <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2019-06-01 08:03:04", 
           "2019-06-01 08:20:04", 
           "2019-06-01 08:33:04", 
           "2019-06-01 08:54:04", 
           "2019-06-01 10:21:04")
)

sheet_csv$Date <- as.POSIXct(sheet_csv$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")

as.data.frame(table(cut(sheet_csv$Date, 
                        breaks = seq.POSIXt(from = round(min(sheet_csv$Date), "hours"), 
                                     to = max(sheet_csv$Date) + .5 * 60 * 60, 
                                     by = "30 min"))))
```

**Output**

```
                 Var1 Freq
1 2019-06-01 08:00:00    2
2 2019-06-01 08:30:00    2
3 2019-06-01 09:00:00    0
4 2019-06-01 09:30:00    0
5 2019-06-01 10:00:00    1
```